# Without loss of generality and basis of a topology

Tags: general-topology

Let X,Y be topological Space and let B be Basis.

In my lecture notes there is a statement that:
If you want to prove that the image of a open set is open one can without loss of generality restrict the open sets to elements of the Basis.

I don't understand why.
Hope someone could help me figure it out.

Comment: $B$ is a basis for which topology?

Comment: Hint: This follows if you know: $$f\left(\bigcup_i U_i\right)=\bigcup_i f(U_i)$$

Comment: plus the facts that any open set can be written as a union of base elements and open sets are closed under all unions.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you I think I got it

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you for the reminder, at the begining I wanted to write more context, hence the continuity in the title. I will Edit it